# Warnings/Comments/Suggestions for low brass player learning tenor sax?

Tags: learning, trombone, saxophone, multi-instrumentalism

Let me start by saying that trombone is my main instrument next to piano and I've been playing it for several years.

I had a fleeting thought about attempting to learn tenor sax. I'm already comfortable with different keys/music theory stuff, so my question is,

are there any tips, suggestions, or warnings that you might offer to a brass player attempting to learn a reed instrument like tenor sax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saxophone at an advanced level will require you to do a bunch of stuff with your throat (voicing) that you probably won't be used to as a trombonist.

I would personally recommend that you keep your trombone practice up as you begin to learn saxophone. The embouchures use somewhat different muscle groups, so practicing both daily will keep you on your toes and enable you to make an easy switch from one to the other without confusing your playing technique on either.

Answer (score 1):

Best tips ever

1) --> book 10 lessons with a teacher that both really knows the instrument and really knows how to teach. The risk if not, is that you will learn a lot of bad habits that you will need to get rid of later. An experienced teacher will start you with the right things.

2) --> practice 15 minutes (or slightly more) every day. The difference between every day and now and then will be enormous.

My story: Amateur level player, played the bass trombone for something like 20 years. Switched to bassoon.

Comment: #1 best advice for any aspiring music student (to a new instrument in this case) for anything; #2 just like everything: a little bit every day is so much better than a lot infrequently.